# Unwanted margin in NavigationView.Content

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, navigationview

I made a simple app that does nothing. It inly displays a NavigationView with two items and a TextBlock as its content. This is the code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="test.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:test"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <NavigationView>
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="First Item" />
                <NavigationViewItem Content="Second Item" />
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>

            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Text="Welcome to my Page"/>
        </NavigationView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My app looks like this:
[image: Screenshot]

Why is there extra space at the top of the TextBlock? And how to remove that space? I know it is possible because the News app uses NavigationView and there is no vertical margin. Here is its screenshot:

[image: News app screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `AlwaysShowHeader` property to False:

```
<NavigationView AlwaysShowHeader="False">
```

This is called out in the [docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#header), though the [new preview version](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/07/23/windows-ui-library-preview-released/) seems to change this behavior currently and not show any header by default.

Comment: I just saw this video: on channel 9 https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Windows/Windows-Developer-Day-Fall-Creators-Update/WinDev010 . Thank You